# Is it possible to change the HostName for a request in ASP.Net on IIS6/7?

Tags: asp.net, iis, url, url-rewriting

Is it possible to change the HostName for a request in ASP.Net?
We need this for rewriting all requests to abc.xyz.com to abc.xyz.com/sites/abc (we are running Sharepoint).
I understand this is possible with ISAPI. We are running IIS7.

Answer (score 1):

I would say you need to use something like [ISA Server](http://www.microsoft.com/forefront/edgesecurity/isaserver/en/us/default.aspx) or possibly [Squid](http://www.squid-cache.org/) which is the user facing gateway to your sharepoint installation.

What you're trying to do is definately possible in ISA Server. (I do that on my installation.).

Comment: ISA Server is overkill IMHO! Squid may do the job but its not HTTP 1.1 compliant. URL Rewriter does the job and even plugs right into the posters' IIS 7 server.

Comment: Possibly if you're just using it for that, yes.

Answer (score 0):

Yes I believe it is possible to do that. See the following [link](http://prodactor.blogspot.com/2007/11/sharepoint-moss-url-rewriting.html). You can use http://urlrewriter.net/ to perform that task. You will need to [learn URLRewrite](http://urlrewriter.net/index.php/support) in order to make this work though.

In order to use this in IIS 7 you will need the URLRewrite Module which can be found [here](http://www.iis.net/extensions/URLRewrite).

Comment: Hi,
I need to write subdomains do subdirectories. It doesn't UrlRewriter on Sharepoint. So if some visits Raw Url: abc.xyz.com, which shows up as "/": , I want the re-written path to be xyz.com/Sites/ which is "/sites/abc" and I additionally want the hostname to be "xyz.com".

Comment: That is definitely possible through URL Rewriter. Just read up some more about it.

Comment: Works with IIS 7 Rewrite Module, but not with Url Rewriter. We need to support both IIS6 and 7 :(

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use [URL Rewrite Module](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/460/using-url-rewrite-module/) in IIS 7.